# Ubuntu 14.10: Sound is not working

Tags: sound, alsa

I've scanned through multiple topics, but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

I keep having the problem of 'dummy output' in Ubuntu 14.10, I've had this problem before in previous iteration how-ever I managed to fix and return my sound.

How-ever, all guides have failed me for now, so I hope someone can help me from the start again.

Problems.
1. Can't open Alsamixer
2. Dummy Output Shown in Sound

I've tried
1. Reinstalling complete Ubuntu desktop
2. Reinstalling Alsamixer/utilities
3. Tried instlaling the Ubuntu developed sound driver

I've been trying to fix it myself for over a week now, but I really can't figure it out.

So basicly, I come here starting at 0 again, tell me what to-do :P

Comment: did you make sure that your sound device is enabled in BIOS? you should enable it there...

Comment: I have never disabled any device in the Bios, I did now know Linux could make any Bios changes?


Basicly

I have several problems

1. I can't acces Alsamixer
2. No Device shows up, in Sound Devices(only Dummy output).
3. Reinstalling: Alsamixer, Gnome/Ubuntu Desktop has not worked.
4. I've tried numerous Guides, which include installing, reinstalling, unblocking etc. Yet problems persist

@aFoP

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem consistently with each version of Ubuntu since 9.04. For me, I had to add the users to the `audio` and `pulse-access` groups, and to do so, you'll need `sudo` rights and a graphical user interface, or a text editor. In my case, I use `vim` from the terminal. You may wish to use `gedit`:

```
    evilsupahfly@black-beast:~$ sudo vim /etc/group
    (enter sudo password)
```

Find the `audio` and `pulse-access` groups (only one group listed per line) and append the users to the list, each with a comma but no space:

```
    audio:x:29:pulse,evilsupahfly,doc-brown,marty_mcfly
    ...
    pulse-access:x:123:evilsupahfly,doc-brown,marty_mcfly
```

Don't change any other groups, and don't erase anything that's already there. Just add the names so they make a list like mine, above (obviously not with those names) and save your changes. After that, usually, logging out and back in will restore sound, but sometimes you need a full-on reboot.

**Edit:** Some non-Unity desktop environments, like Cinnamon (to name just one), will allow you to manage the group settings right from the user settings control panel, but sadly, default Unity doesn't (see screenshot) requiring you to manually edit `/etc/group` to make the changes.

[image]